# How to access/send Orbeon form data from/to third party apps?

Tags: forms, orbeon, sap-commerce-cloud

In Hybris 6.3, I am working with Orbeon Forms. I have created a simple form. After clicking on the Save button, my form is getting saved in the database in XML format. I am facing the following issues:

1. The data format should be sent using form parameters (normal form submission).
2. I want to send data to a third party app or access the data from third party app.
3. The file upload is not working.

Comment: 1. In your first point, what do you mean by "data format"? 2. When do you want the data to be submitted? Right away upon "save"? 3. What functionality are you referring to as "document upload"? Are you trying to attach a file to a file attachment field in a form?

Comment: I believe that file attachments are not yet supported by the Hybris integration, if I recall properly.

Comment: 1) "data format" in the sense, It should send data as we are taking input through form input fields. like username, email like fields. current format is xml. 2) I want to submit data after clicking on save, after proper validation. 3) I am attaching a file to a file attachment field. getting uploaded. but when clicked on save, throwing error

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. can you please let me know about accessing the data to/from third party like SAP systems.